# cut command to split comma separated value having spaces

Tags: unix, cut

I have file something like

```
aaaaa, aa 1
bbbbb, bb2
cccccccc, ccc 3/2
```

and i want comma separated value that mean something like

```
aaaaa
aa 1
```

in first iteration

```
bbbbb
bb2
```

in second iteration and so on

can some one help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS=, read one two; do
  echo "$one"      # aaaaa on first iteration
  echo "$two"      # aa 1 on first iteration
done < input-file
```